# Cannot get wtf-tinymce to work with my Flask App

Tags: flask, tinymce, flask-wtforms

I am trying to use wtf-tinymce to integrate a TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor into my Flask application. However, the resulting web page only displays an empty textbox and not the TinyMCE editor.

I've followed the instructions provided here: https://github.com/azsoftware/wtf-tinymce including initializing wtf-tinymce and adding all relevant code into my templates. I found someone with the same problem [here](https://github.com/azsoftware/wtf-tinymce/issues/3) but the only suggestion is to initialize the module and I have already done that.

This is my html page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% import 'wtf_tinymce/editor.html' as tinymce with context %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="/newtext">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.title.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.title.errors %}
                        {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.title.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.content.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.content.errors %}
                        {{ form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.content.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ tinymce.init_wtf_tinymce(default_content_css='css/tinymce.css') }}
{% endblock %}
```

And here is the code in forms.py:

```
class NewPost(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired(message="All texts must have a title")])
    content = TinyMceField(
        'Content',
        tinymce_options={'toolbar': 'bold italic | link | code'}, validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    submit = SubmitField('submit', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

In theory, this should produce a WYSIWYG editor on the html page, but instead I just get a normal blank textbox.

EDIT: If anyone is having the same problem, https://bzdww.com/article/38020/ has a better way to integrate TinyMCE and flask-wtforms

Comment: The link you provided is not responding

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, then:
forms.py: https://github.com/annie-primera/datacollection_v2/blob/master/datacollection/forms.py
html code: https://github.com/annie-primera/datacollection_v2/blob/master/datacollection/templates/basiceditor.html